# Syntax error: Unexpected token (45:16) on handleChange in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get value of `TextField` using state. I have added `onChange` on it and calling `handleChange`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    injectTapEventPlugin();
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: false, noteVal: "" };
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleCreateNote = () => {
    console.log("Hey");
  };

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({noteVal: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.fab}
            backgroundColor={colors.blue_color}
            onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            title={strings.dialog_create_note_title}
          >
            <TextField
              hintText="Note"
              style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
              defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />

            <div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "48",
                backgroundColor: "red",
                float: "left",
                visibility: "hidden"
              }}
            />

            <FlatButton
              label={strings.create_note}
              style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
              onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
            />
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am getting below error

```
./src/App.js
Syntax error: D:/React JS/todo-app/src/App.js: Unexpected token (45:16)

  43 |   };
  44 | 
> 45 |   handleChange: function(event) {
     |                 ^
  46 |     this.setState({noteVal: event.target.value});
  47 |   }
  48 |
```

Can anyone help me what has went wrong?

Comment: remove function keyword and colon, write it like this: `handleChange(event) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). Since you are inside class body declaration you need to replace

```
 handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({noteVal: event.target.value});
  }
```

with

```
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({noteVal: event.target.value});
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean if I define a method outside a class then I need to go through with my approach. Is this ?

Comment: What does it mean "define a method outside a class"? In object literals you could use both syntax `const obj = { fn() {return 'es2015'}, fnES5Way: function() {return  'es5'}}`. If you are defining prototype method in class body declaration - only the short one.

Comment: What do you mean by  "object literals"

Comment: Literally "object literals" :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals js has one :)